# MarkLogic content pump (MLCP) with GUI

Tags: user-interface, web, xquery, marklogic, mlcp

I've tried using the mlcp pump through the terminal with ease following 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump

but I have no clue on how to implement the mlcp function with a user interface in a website. I've searched the whole internet-sphere but to no avail.

Please help

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, and explain what you are trying to achieve? There are plenty ways to ingest data, and MLCP is just one of the possible solutions..

Answer (score 2):

MLCP is a Java program. The source code is also available. It was written as a command-line tool. However there is nothing stopping you from using the libraries (or other wrapper scripts) for managing these tasks through a web interface.

Comment: There is no such GUI right now, but if you chose to start such a project on GitHub, you may find others who would be interested in helping. I'm the Technical Community Manager for MarkLogic; let me know if you (or anyone else) would like to pursue this.

Comment: Dave, don't tempt us.  An Angular.js library to expose a web-enabled extended version of LocalJobRunner sounds fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a GUI on web page that connects to MLCP underneath, then this project might give you some rough idea: [mlcpGui](https://github.com/heelix/mlcpGui)

If you need a more user-friendly MLCP (like a GUI), then this project is **highly recommended**: [iMLCP](https://github.com/mattsunsjf/iMLCP)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of invoking mlcp programmatically (in this case, from within an Apache Camel component) - https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-camel-mlcp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rjrudin/marklogic/camel/component/mlcp/MlcpProducer.java - you could adapt this to invoke it in your UI.